# Exception caught by @ExceptionHandler is not returned to client as a response, rather jetty is returning generic status code 500, why?

Tags: spring-mvc

**This is the global exception handler class that should deal with the exceptions:**

```
package org.example.myapp.exceptions;

@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerAdvice {

    private record ErrorContent(Instant timestamp, String errorMessage){}

    @ExceptionHandler(SkillNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorContent> handleSkillNotFoundException(SkillNotFoundException exception){
        System.out.println("handle me pls!"); //<------- this is being printed, so I assume this exception handler method caught the exception
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(new ErrorContent(
                Instant.now(),
                exception.getMessage()
                ));
    }

}
```

**Config class for the DispacherServlet:**

```
package org.example.myapp.config;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.example.myapp.controllers", "org.example.myapp.exceptions"})
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class ServletConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {}
```

**Config class for the root app:**

```
package org.example.myapp.config;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.example.myapp")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "org.example.myapp.repositories")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class RootConfig {

    /////SOME JPA/HIBERNATE CONFIGURATIONS HERE

}
```

**Class to delegate configs:**

```
package org.example.myapp.config;

public class AppConfig extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {RootConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {ServletConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
}
```

So the flow is:
Controller gets request -> service method gets called -> repo method gets called -> service method throws SkillNotFoundException -> exception delegation ends up on this Advice class -> appropriate exception handler method is found and called -> as i said above the System.out message is printed but return is ignored(?) -> exception message is appropriately logged in stack trace as well -> jetty returns status code 500 to my postman instead of what I wanted from the exception handler message.

Any solutions to this?

Comment: I tried reproducing your Advice class and running locally with Spring Boot it returned 404 as desired when checking in the browser dev tools.

Comment: Well, I'm not working in spring boot, I'm working in standard spring, which could mean I am missing some additional configuration for something? @scrhartley

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: rebooted my PC.....
I have no idea why this fixed it but it did.....